# Firebase client library for ROBOVM

Tags: firebase, robovm

I am developing a mobile app with Robovm for ios.
I need to use Firebase in my app.
Is there any way to use Firebase in Robovm?

Answer (score 1):

Update: we have added Firebase Analytics to our Robovm app and documented how to do that at https://www.squins.com/knowledge/adding-firebase-analytics-to-a-robovm-ios-app/

Original reply:

You will have to create bindings manually.

Some instructions to get started: https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm/wiki/How-are-bindings-to-existing-native-frameworks-generated%3F

On their Gitter chat-room, another libgdx developer is trying to achieve exactly that and he is being helped out by the maintainers of Robovm :-).

https://gitter.im/MobiDevelop/robovm?at=58d043dab809ca5f4a654424